# NumPy array as quasi-hash table

Tags: python, numpy, hash-map

Motivation: I have a large number of large read-only dicts with large string keys mapped to tuples of two floats. They are taking up a large amount of heap space.

Proposed solution: a 3xn NumPy array, with the first column being the hash value of the key, and sorted by that column. Only contains and `getitem` ops are required for my needs.

I realize that this solution is \$O(log(n))\$ rather than \$O(c)\$ but I assume that this isn't that big a problem for my application as there aren't that many lookups per request and my primary problem is memory constraints.

I'm not sure how well `searchsorted` performs here though, or if I should try to change the stride somehow so that the first column is contiguous or something like that. I should also probably be using a record array.

```
import numpy

class FCD(object):

  def __init__(self, d):
    data = []
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
      data.append((hash(key), value[0], value[1]))
    data.sort()
    self.data = numpy.array(data)

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    hkey = hash(key)
    ix = numpy.searchsorted(self.data[:, 0], hkey)
    if ix < len(self.data) and self.data[ix][0] == hkey:
      return self.data[ix][1:]
    else:
      raise KeyError

  def __contains__(self, key):
    hkey = hash(key)
    ix = numpy.searchsorted(self.data[:, 0], hkey)
    return ix < len(self.data) and self.data[ix][0] == hkey
```

Comment: I am a little confused as to why you do not just use a `dict` here. Can you prove that your solution is more memory efficient. The lookups will certainly be slower.

Comment: @ebarr: A tuple of two floats costs 40 + 24 + 24 = 84 bytes, and each dictionary slot costs 24 bytes, so there's a potential saving of 84 bytes per entry using the mechanism described.

Answer (score 3):

I think this looks pretty efficient.  Let me add a few more minor, detailed comments (more than 1 year after the question was asked; I hope they are still useful):

1. After you convert to a NumPy array, the keys are longer guaranteed to be unique (if someone re-uses your code in a different context, etc).  This will cause `searchsorted` to fail.  You might want to add a check such as:

   ```
   assert len(self.data[:, 0]) == len(np.unique(self.data[:, 0])
   ```

   to make sure users and readers of your code know that the first column of your array must be unique.
2. I agree that record arrays (aka structured arrays) would be better.  Your code would be more readable because instead of things like:

   ```
   self.data[ix][1:]
   ```

   you could write:

   ```
   self.data[ix]['Float_1'], self.data[ix]['Float_2']
   ```

   (but please use more descriptive names for your context than `'Float_1` etc.!)

   Also, and *more importantly: without using a structured array, your hash keys will be stored as floats instead of ints*.  That will take extra memory, and make future calls to `searchsorted` and `__eq` slightly less efficient.
3. Your `__contains__` method seems overly stringent to me, which would result in it being slower.  Do you need to call `searcshorted` in `__contains__` at all?  Wouldn't something like this suffice and be more efficient?

   ```
   def __contains__(self, key):
       hkey = hash(key)
       return np.in1d(self.data[:, 0], hkey).any()
   ```
4. You are duplicating the `__contains__` check in your `__getitem__` code.  I'd just say it this way:

   ```
   if __contains__(self, key): return self.data[ix][1:]
   ```
5. Very minor, but the idiom is always `import numpy as np`.  It's probably best to use that so you can do `np.searchsorted` etc. instead of typing `numpy.searchsorted` as that's what most NumPy users do.